# How to Render ng2Chart (Barchart ) dynamically using angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, ng2-charts, angular4-forms

I used ng2charts module to render charts. If i try with below dummy data, bar chart rendering properly.

**Typescript**

```
  public barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true
  };
  public barChartLabels: string[] = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3'];
  public barChartType: string = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend: boolean = true;

  public barChartData: any[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80], label: 'Data1' },
    { data: [28, 48, 40], label: 'Data2' },
    { data: [30, 28, 80], label: 'Data3' }
  ];
```

**Component Html :**

```
<canvas style="height:230px" baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

But If i tried to get data from server and set data dynamically not working as expected.

I'm Getting below error

> HomeComponent.html:73 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Please refer my below code.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  serverData: any;

  public barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true
  };


  public barChartLabels: string[];
  public barChartType: string = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend: boolean = true;

  public barChartData: any[];


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private Service: Service,
    private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private _configService: ConfigService) {
    this.getApis();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const loggedInUser = new LoggedInUser();
    const user = loggedInUser.getLoggedUser();
    if (user != null) {
      this.loggedInUserId = loggedInUser.getLoggedUser().UserId;
    }

  }

  getApis() {
    this._configService.get()
      .subscribe(c => {
        this.apiEndpoints = c;
        this.loadDashBoardDetails();
      },
      error => { this.msg = <any>error; });
  }

  loadDashBoardDetails() {
    this.indLoading = true;
    this.Service.get("APIENDPOINT")
      .subscribe(c => {
        this.serverData = c[0];
        this.loadserverData();
        this.indLoading = false;
      },
      error => {
        this.msg = <any>error;
      }

      );
  }
  loadserverData() {
    let chartData: any[];
    let data1 = '';
    let data2 = '';
    let data3 = '';
    this.barChartLabels = new Array<string>();
    chartData = new Array<any>();
    for (let _i = 0; _i < this.serverData.length; _i++) {
      this.barChartLabels.push(this.serverData[_i].Code);
      if (data1 === '') {
        data1 = this.serverData[_i].Target;
      } else {
        data1 = data1 + ',' + this.serverData[_i].data1;
      }

      if (data2 === '') {
        data2 = this.serverData[_i].data2;
      } else {
        data2 = data2 + ',' + this.serverData[_i].data2;
      }

      if (data3 === '') {
        data3 = this.serverData[_i].data3;
      } else {
        data3 = data3 + ',' + this.serverData[_i].data3;
      }
    }

    chartData.push({
      data: data1,
      label: 'data1 label'

    });

    chartData.push({
      data: data2,
      label: 'data2 label'

    });

    chartData.push({
      data: data3,
      label: 'data3 label'

    });

    this.barChartData = chartData;
  }
 }
```

Comment: where are using the value `property data`?

Comment: data is a object of the barChartData. See above dummy data and adding dynamic data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because the data is undefined when the chart is rendered.  You can avoid this by using `*ngIf` on your chart

```
<canvas
    *ngIf="barChartData"
    baseChart
    style="height:230px" 
    [datasets]="barChartData" 
    [labels]="barChartLabels" 
    [options]="barChartOptions" 
    [legend]="barChartLegend" 
    [chartType]="barChartType" 
    (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" 
    (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
</canvas>
```

The above HTML will not be rendered until the data is resolved.  Once the data is resovled and barChartData is no longer undefined, the chart will be rendered.

---

EDIT:

The chart won't rerender if you keep adding data to the `barChartData` array. When you get your data, instead of pushing it to the `barChartData` array, create a local array to build the data.  Then assign the local array to `barChartData` when all the data is populated in the local array.  Ng2Charts doesn't rerender until the reference to the array changes or you manually call for it to rerender.

---

EDIT2

Your data also should be of type `number`. You have `data1 = '';`

Comment: If i add above ngIf comment it is always showing empty chart. Please share sample code to render dynamic bar chart using ngchart

Comment: Yes data1 should be a number array. Its working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Modify the condition of `ngIf` to `barchartData.length > 0`

```
<div *ngIf="barChartData.length > 0"
    <canvas
        baseChart
        style="height:230px" 
        [datasets]="barChartData" 
        [labels]="barChartLabels" 
        [options]="barChartOptions" 
        [legend]="barChartLegend" 
        [chartType]="barChartType" 
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" 
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Update 1 :

Yes you are not initializing the array.

```
public barChartData: any[] = [ ]
```

Comment: Already i tried this. But no luck. I beleive problem with adding object to barChartdata. but i cannot find out.

Comment: I already initialized array inside loadkpiInfo method ex.  chartData = new Array<any>(); that is not an issue

Comment: Yes `chartData` is assigned to the object `barChartdata` at your `onInit()` or even later. but the DOM is rendered before it gets called. Because of which you are facing the `undefined` error

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to initialise the barchart data property before ngoninit()
Make sure you rendered yuur server data to a proper array console.log it to verify 
then define for eg:this.barChartData=[your array] then you will get if that won't work 
change [datasets] to [data] in html